# Data from web-page to a text box in application?

Tags: vb6

I saw a program(RAPGET) which downloads a file from RapidShare for the given link?

I like to design a program like this which gets the information about weather-forecast from a web-page and it should display in the textbox in vb6?

Comment: Also, anybody know how the program RAPGET is designed? I am really excited after seeing that program! How can a desktop application get an information from a web-page? Its really mind-blowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a web service from VB6. Here's "[the easy way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730836(VS.80).aspx)" to do it.

Or you can ncheck out the replies to [this previous SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122607/what-is-the-best-way-to-consume-a-web-service-from-vb6/122645)

Answer (score 1):

You can use winHttp component that ship with winxp and above. It ships as a package called BITS [background intelligent transfer service]. Using this you can make calls to Http and Ftp servers. So this will enable your VB6 application to act as an HttpClient which will receive the data from the weather server.

Second thing is the server. You must know in which format you are getting the data from the server. Is it plain text ?, Soap ? or XML ? once you identify the format of data transport you can receive the data from the server using winHttp and parse them in your application and fetch the desired data.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok thanks, but Rapidshare doesnt send any xml files while using http get/post method. Its simply sends a html document. Since it uses php. I am a beginner to all these. Since i like to know? Anybody help me from a-z of these concepts?

Comment: this might be a bad idea in a long run. As the majority of websites moved to https-only paradigm (where https often uses a too-new-for-vb6 encryption method), such approach will likely not deliver you with the desired pages, at least in absence of http<->https proxy server