# Visual Basic 6 WSDL Soap Proxy

Tags: web-services, vb6, wsdl

How would I go about generating Visual Basic 6 Proxy dll/tlb from a WSDL file?

Similar to the [WSDL2Java](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL) for java, but for Visual Basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could generate a Web Service client proxy using one of the tools available in .NET, either through **Visual Studio** or one of the command-line programs (*wsdl.exe* when using **ASMX** or *svcutil.exe* when using **WCF**) and [make the resulting class and its containing assembly available to COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439(VS.71).aspx).

If you want a VB6 native solution, I believe your best choice is using the [SOAP Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C943C0DD-CEEC-4088-9753-86F052EC8450&displaylang=en).

Also, see this related question on SO:
[**What is the best way to consume a web service from VB6?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122607/what-is-the-best-way-to-consume-a-web-service-from-vb6)

Comment: I strongly recommend using a COM object created through .NET and WCF. The SOAP toolkit is extremely obsolete. Doing it via .NET gives you the best of both worlds - the modern tool support of .NET while still using VB6.