# Consume a Coldfusion webservice from VB6

Tags: web-services, vb6, coldfusion-8, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to consume a webservice using VB6; I don't have much experience with VB6 and i was told that i should use XMLHTTP to do this. But i am unsure how to go about all of this; the webservice take's in a string and returns a string. Since the webservice is all cold fusion tags do i need to parse out the string to be displayed? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer to your question is here:
[What is the best way to consume a web service from VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122607/what-is-the-best-way-to-consume-a-web-service-from-vb6)

The above assumes that the target is actually a web-service, which accepts and emits an XML document.  This may not necessarily be the case. In many cases a programmable web endpoint may truly just accept a string and return a simple string. In this case you wouldn't need to produce an XML document for the outgoing message; often you just need to construct the (GET) URL string with your parameters appropriately.  Nor would you need to consume or parse the response as an XML document; here it may be only string parsing that is required.

For more specific answers on what to do with the response once you get it in VB6, provide an example of the input and output messages, and describe what you want out of them, and we'll try to provide some additional suggestions.

Comment: Right now i am only testing to see if i can make a connection. the Web-service takes in a string and then returns "The string you entered" then says the string entered. What i am trying to do is to get the connection and pass the web-service the string and get back the response in a VB text field.

Comment: +1 BTW I took the liberty of editing your answer to fix the link. Looks like you pasted it twice.

Comment: @MarkJ, Thank you very very much (*I wanted to just say "thanks" but I needed padding to reach the 15 character minimum for comments)