# The easiest and portable way to do standard URL Encoding in VB6?

Tags: unicode, vb6, utf-8, urlencode

Our company has a VB6 program, and it now needs to be integrated with some internal web applications / web services. In order to interact with those web services, parameters need to be URL-encoded. However, VB6 doesn't provide such as HttpUtility.UrlEncode(), as well as the default charset is Unicode rather than UTF-8. I'm seeking a most easier and portable way to make the VB6 web request to conform to the standard. Please kindly advise.

Thanks!
William Choi

Comment: You might also like to look at some [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516119/get-post-to-restful-web-service) questions on [calling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122607/what-is-the-best-way-to-consume-a-web-service-from-vb6) web services from VB6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider [UrlEscape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773774%28VS.85%29.aspx) in shlwapi.dll.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the helpers listed in the following link. They're really helpful and portable.
[Unicode string to UTF8 bytes in VB6.0](http://www.nonhostile.com/howto-convert-byte-array-utf8-string-vb6.asp)

Answer (score -1):

You may have to write your own encoder.

It's not terribly difficult.

This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) can help you get started.