# How to Consume a SOAP Web Service in VB6?

Tags: vb6, wsdl

I want to consume a file which is wsdl with VB6 , anyone can help me? Or how can I convert wsdl to proxy class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at either Microsoft's SOAP Toolkit or [PocketSOAP](http://www.pocketsoap.com/pocketsoap/).  Might be best to look at both, but don't despair over the learning curve.  Both offer simple approaches for simple situations as well as complex solutions for more complex ones.

Comment: Looks like this is where to get the SOAP toolkit now: http://download.cnet.com/SOAP-Toolkit/3000-10250_4-10730985.html

Comment: I pulled out the old link. Microsoft is gradually removing one download after another, and it may be as much due to their "Who programs on the desktop?" worldview as anything else now. This was the excuse they gave when their ADO compatibility break in Win7 SP1 was brought to their attention.

Comment: Bunch of geniuses and boneheads.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a problem with terminology: you do not want to consume the file. The file is a description of a web service. It is the web service that you want to consume. The WSDL gives you all the information you need to consume it.

There are methods to consume a web service in VB6. In the same way you shouldn't be using VB6, you shouldn't be using any of these methods.

You should use VB.NET to create a small COM component. This component will consume the service by using "Add Service Reference" to create proxy classes. You will be able to use modern tools and techniques to develop and debug this component.

You can then consume the COM component from VB6, just like any other COM component.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you can use the SOAP moniker like this

```
Set oProxy = GetObject("soap:wsdl=http://server/folder/service.wsdl")
oProxy.Method "Param1"
```

You can check out the answers to [What is the best way to consume a web service from VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122607/what-is-the-best-way-to-consume-a-web-service-from-vb6)

Comment: -1: reading those answers shows that this doesn't work on Vista or above.

Comment: @John which answer would that be? [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122607/what-is-the-best-way-to-consume-a-web-service-from-vb6/122645#122645) says it works on XP or above, which would include Vista

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122607/what-is-the-best-way-to-consume-a-web-service-from-vb6/156178#156178