# Windows Service written in .NET accessible from VB6

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, windows-services

I have to develop a Windows Service in .NET/C#. The service must be accessible from a VB6 application.

My first idea was to host a WCF service in a Windows Service, but the VB6 application needs a wrapper for the service to be able to consume it. This is not an option.

Now I'm thinking of using sockets, but is this the best approach? If not, what would be the best design?

I would like to know what my options are, and what are the pros and cons for these options?

Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: Yes, sockets, would be one of your limited options since you can't use the optimal solution.

Comment: Why is it not an option to write a COM-accessible .NET assembly that the VB6 app references and deals with the communication to the .NET service?  I've used this exact approach and it works great.

Comment: In the VB6 application they are already using services and they call them using WinSocket. They want to maintain a uniform way of calling the services they use.

Answer (score 2):

You can [host your WCF services as COM+ applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735856.aspx#_Toc156817373).

Once you have a WCF service hosted in COM+, you can generate a type library from the COM+ application and then reference that in your VB6 code.

Note that you'll have to have the .NET runtime installed on the machine that the WCF service is hosted on (but not on the machines that you install a COM+ proxy on if using distributed calls).

Comment: This is a very nice option! However, instead of using COM+ the VB6 team requires to use Winsocket...

Comment: @DirkV Then you're asking a question which you have only a single answer to, and is localized to you?  Why does the VB6 team require Winsocket?  This was not a requirement of the question as it was asked.

Comment: You are absolutely right! They gave me the requirement after I suggested your solution... But I'm still thankfull for your contribution ;-)

Comment: @DirkV Bleh, that sucks.  Their requirement doesn't make sense either, given that now they have to hand code pretty much all communication across the wire, which is highly inefficient from a DEV point of view.

Answer (score 0):

The WCF service is still an option, but you would have to ensure the WCF configured binding is interoperable (choose [BasicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx) for example as seen here: [WCF Bindings In Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163394.aspx)).

On the VB6 side, you can call an existing SOAP endpoint, as described here for example: [How to Consume a SOAP Web Service in VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104143/how-to-consume-a-soap-web-service-in-vb6)