# VB 6 connecting to a Web service

Tags: web-services, vb6

I have an URL of a web service "http://webservices.daehosting.com/services/TemperatureConversions.wso?op=CelciusToFahrenheit"

All I want is to have it called from a vb 6 code. I am new to VB 6. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Consume a SOAP Web Service in VB6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104143/how-to-consume-a-soap-web-service-in-vb6)

Answer (score 1):

Add a webbrowser control to your form (it is in the components of Microsoft Internet Controls) and use the .Navigate method

Comment: @Rajdeep If you found good solution please consider posting it here as your answer.