# MS Excel 2010 VBA: SOAP over HTTPS with proxy-based and basic authentication

Tags: vba, excel, soap, https

How feasible is it with VBA in MS Excel 2010 to make a SOAP call over HTTPS with proxy-based authentication and basic access authentication?

I've implemented the same SOAP calls in Python and Perl scripts, but would like to make these calls in Excel via a macro.

After some investigating, there doesn't seem to be any supported SOAP library for MS Excel 2010 with the functionality that's required to authenticate.

Comment: This question has been asked before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104143/how-to-consume-a-soap-web-service-in-vb6.   The bottom line is you use the Microsoft SOAP Toolkit to access web services from VB6/VBA.

Comment: @joehanna the Microsoft SOAP Toolkit is only supported up to Excel 2007, leaving Excel 2010 as unsupported